# Partitioning a sparse matrix into minimum number of components

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, matrix, graph-algorithm

How can I partition a sparse matrix into minimum number of connected components such that each component has a common row or column throughout the component. What data structure should I use to do this task in minimum time.I thought that to do so I must maximize the number of elements in each component so while taking the input I stored number of elements in each row and column. I sorted the lists and then row or column with max(min(element in row, elements in column)),i.e,

```
   row 5-1   column 4-2
   row 4-1   column 3-2
   row 3-2   column 2-3
   row 2-2   column 1-3
   row 1-10
```

for a matrix:

```
 x
 x
x x
x  x
xxxxxxxxxx
```

(x represents non-zero positions)(The final output should be 4 for this matrix)

where bottom left corner is 1,1

Then I will first remove column 1.Then I will have to update the remaining arrays which is taking up lot of time and also storing list for each row and column is not feasible because it uses lot of memory. I just have to tell minimum number of partitions and not actually partition the matrix. In the given matrix it can be partitioned by taking (row1,row2,row3,colum2-(1,2)) as partitions.

EDIT:Or equivalently we can think of this as a set a elements which have two numbers associated with them and we have output minimum number of partitions such that each partition has one of the two number as common.

Comment: I don't find this exposition clear. For starters, each component has a common row or column with what?

Comment: @clwhisk each partition has a common row or column  with elements of the same partition. for example a partition can be ( (1,1) (1,5) (1,10) (1,22323) ) which has row1 as common but it cant be ( (1,1) (1,5) (2,5) (1,22323) ) because neither row nor column is common throughout the partition.

Comment: But it sounds like ((1,1) (1,2) (1,3) (1,4) ... ) is going to be the answer. You said something about the maximum number of elements in a row, but it's not a statement of the problem.

Comment: @clwhisk I dont have to produce the partition with maximum elements but produce minimum number partitions of the matrix such that union of those partitions gives back the matrix

Comment: @clwhisk Here the minimum number of partitions can be formed by taking row1 into one partition then row2 and row3 and then column2 but just excluding the element (1,2) because it has already been added in row1 partition.

Comment: Isn't the matrix itself a trivial solution? One component! I think you need shorter sentences, one of which might mention empty rows or minimizing row count.

Comment: @clwhisk the whole matrix does not necessarily have all elements with a row or column common with all other elements. whole of matrix can be solution only when all non zero elements are in row or in a column

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will find these lecture slides relevant: http://www.cs.indiana.edu/classes/b673/notes/GraphPartitioning.pdf

Comment: No these didnt help, but thanks for trying to find out solution to problem